# WebStorm - select all text from cursor

Tags: visual-studio-code, webstorm

I want to select all text from the cursor to the end of the document or to the start of the document. I moved from VSCode which has a shortcut for this:

<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow UP/DOWN</kbd>

and in VSCode keymap settings it looks like this:

[image]

I was trying to find this in WebStorm but with no results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature is called either "Move Caret to Text Start with Selection" or "Move Caret to Text End with Selection" and can be found either with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> (Windows Find Action), <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> (Mac Find Action), or in Settings under Keymap by using the search box. Under Settings Keymap it is possible to assign this to a different keystroke combination.

On Windows <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd>

On Mac <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> if the keyboard is lacking Home and End substitute <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Left Arrow</kbd> and <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Right Arrow</kbd>

Comment: Where do I find Home and End on MAC Keyboard?

Comment: @Freestyle09 https://www.google.com/search?q=mac+home+key+shortcut&tbm=isch **P.S.** You can assign your own shortcuts that will work better withyour keyboard (`Preferences | Keymap` -- just locate the right action (use search box)).